# calling inner function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 3 pieces of codes:

Code 1:

```
var object = {
  someMethod: function(a) { console.log("hello") }
};
```

Code 2:

```
var object = {
  someMethod: function(a) { calling() }
};
function calling(){console.log("i am calling me");}
```

Code 3:

```
var wrapper = function(){
    add: function(key, value){ localStorage.setItem(key, value) }
};
```

Only Code 3 seems to fail: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ((…) VM296:3 is the error it gives in Chrome. Can someone please explain what's wrong with it?

My idea is to create a function 'wrapper' and 'add', 'delete' and 'update' methods inside it, so as to access them as: wrapper.add(param1, param2);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example, you have an object named `object` and it has a method `someMethod` which prints to the console.

In the second example, you have an object with a method and a global function. The method of the object calls the global function.

In the third example, you have a function and you are trying to add a method to the function. This doesn't work. You can add methods to objects. It should be like this:

```
var wrapper = {
    add: function (key, value) {
        localStorage.setItem(key, value);
    }
};
```

and access it using `wrapper.add(key, value)`.

---

Also, in Luka's answer, the first example he gave is not an object but an object constructor. If you use the following code

```
var wrapper = function(){
   this.add = function(key, value){ localStorage.setItem(key, value) }
};
```

you can't access it using `wrapper.add(key, value)`. First you need to create the object using the constructor `new wrapper()` and then access the method.

```
var myObject = new wrapper();
myObject.add(key, value);

// or

new wrapper().add(key, value);
```

Which I think this is not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
var wrapper = function(){
   this.add = function(key, value){ localStorage.setItem(key, value) }
};
```

It's a different syntax if you're using object notation with `{}` or with `function(){}`

They basically serve the same purpose in your case, but the syntax is different. 
You could of course also write it like the other two.

```
var wrapper = {
    add: function(key, value){ localStorage.setItem(key, value) }
};
```